# OpenCV, dlib - image type conversion failes in a function; works outside

Tags: c++, opencv, dlib

The logic of the program is as follows:

```
using namespace dlib;

int main()
{
    while (flag)
    {
        cv::Mat3b frame0;
        camera0 >> frame0;
        cv::imshow("Video0", frame0);

        array2d<rgb_pixel> img;
        assign_image(img, cv_image<bgr_pixel>(frame0));
        cv::imshow("Video0_processed", toMat(img));
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And it works just fine.

When I change it to

```
cv::Mat3b convert_back_and_forth(cv::Mat3b cv_img);

int main()
{
    while (flag)
    {
        cv::Mat3b frame0;
        camera0 >> frame0;
        cv::imshow("Video0", frame0);

        cv::imshow("Video0_processed", convert_back_and_forth(frame0));
        ...
    }
    ...
}

cv::Mat3b convert_back_and_forth(cv::Mat3b cv_img)
{
    array2d<rgb_pixel> img;
    assign_image(img, cv_image<bgr_pixel>(cv_img));
    return toMat(img);
}
```

It crashes without any error. The program simply terminates.

A version

```
cv::Mat3b convert_back_and_forth(cv::Mat3b cv_img);

int main()
{
    cv::Mat3b frame0;
    while (flag)
    {
        camera0 >> frame0;
        cv::imshow("Video0", frame0);
        ...
    }
    cv::imshow("Video0_processed", convert_back_and_forth(frame0));
    ...
}

cv::Mat3b convert_back_and_forth(cv::Mat3b cv_img)
{
    array2d<rgb_pixel> img;
    assign_image(img, cv_image<bgr_pixel>(cv_img));
    return toMat(img);
}
```

works. But of course the functionality is not the same. What is the difference between the 1st and the 2nd versions? Why the initial can possibly work whilst the latter fails?

**EDIT:**

I have just found that if I declare `array2d<rgb_pixel> img` in a global scope, the 2nd version of the program works. Nevertheless it does not really answer the question.

Comment: Btw declaring the variable of the `cv::Mat` **outside** the loop is the preferable way of doing things. This is simply a matter of efficiency. After the first iteration the variable will "point" at a memory chunk with the size specified by the first captured frame. Each consecutive iteration will overwrite the data at that location in memory instead of creating a new one, which is exactly what happens if you create a variable inside a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the documentation for dlib::toMat? :)

The documentation for [dlib::toMat()](http://dlib.net/dlib/opencv/to_open_cv_abstract.h.html) says this:

returns an OpenCV Mat object which represents the same image as img.  This
              is done by setting up the Mat object to point to the same memory as img.
              **Therefore, the returned Mat object is valid only as long as pointers
              to the pixels in img remain valid**.